# Project Structure tab not able to open in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to change some external libs in build.gradle file.For that reason I need to go to File->Project Structure in Android studio.
But i'm not able to open that option.Please help.

Comment: You didn't say what happens when you try to open that option. Is there an error message?

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila Once I click File->Project Struture ,then it does not show anything .

Comment: Thanks @Raghavendra ..It worked for me.

Comment: @guna Please, accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

just go to View-> Tool Windows and add structure

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in Android studio

Check this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189002

try this remove SDK 19 and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

do as below-

1. Change from Android tab -> Project tab
2. Goto File and then u can find Project Structure.

or simply try the shortcut

Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S